# Extending PHP's SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml

I'm sending XML documents to outside vendors, and one of them is having trouble parsing our XML because single and double quotes are present in the XML content. I know that per the official XML spec these only need to be escaped when used in attributes, but I figured that it wouldn't be too much difficulty to extend PHP's SimpleXMLElement to make it escape quotes. This was not the case. My first attempt was this:

```
<?php
class BetterXMLElement extends SimpleXMLElement
{
    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        echo "called __set with $name and $value";
        $this->addChild($name, $value);
    }

    public function addChild($name, $value=null, $ns=null)
    {
        $new_value = strtr($value, [
            '&' => '&amp;',
            '"' => '&quot;',
            "'" => '&apos;',
        ]);
        echo "New Value: $new_value\n";
        parent::addChild($name, $new_value, $ns);
    }
}

$xml = new BetterXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TRANSACTION></TRANSACTION>');
$xml->COST = "apos: ', amp: &, quot: \"";
$xml->addChild('PRODUCT', "apos: ', amp: &, quot: \"");
echo $xml->asXML();
```

The above code outputs:

```
New Value: apos: &apos;, amp: &amp;, quot: &quot;
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TRANSACTION><COST>apos: ', amp: &amp;, quot: "</COST><PRODUCT>apos: ', amp: &amp;, quot: "</PRODUCT></TRANSACTION>
```

What this indicates to me is:

1. The echo in `__set` is not being called, as I would expect it to be when I am setting COST. Why isn't this working?
2. My override on addChild is getting called when I set PRODUCT, but the HTML entities for the quotes are getting transformed back when asXML is called. Why does it work like this? Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: Some code sample which shows how to reproduce the issue would be helpful here.

Comment: @JakubMatczak good point, I added some example usage and output!

Comment: The `SimpleXMLElement` class is not a regular class. It looks like a class but it does a lot of things in not-regular ways. I recommend you use `DOMDocument` instead. It provides the [`loadXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) and [`saveXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) to serialize the document as XML text and many methods to inspect and modify its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's no clean built-in way to do what I needed to do with either SimpleXMLElement or DOMDocument due to the inherent design of libxml2. I ended up replacing the necessary characters with placeholders before XML processing (e.g. a single quote gets replaced with "{quot}") and then swapping those placeholders with the appropriate HTML entity in the XML output.

Also, as axiac pointed out in a previous comment, SimpleXMLElement is not a normal PHP class, which is why my override attempts were failing.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use simple xml - It's rubbish!

Instead try DOMDocument()!

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$hello = $dom->createElement('hello');
$hello->setAttribute('such', 'wow');
$text = new DOMText('This & That');
$hello->appendChild($text);
$dom->appendChild($hello);
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Which will create the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <hello such="wow">This &amp; That</hello>
```